# Magento2 Admin Login Redirects to Login Page With No Error

Tags: magento2, admin, login

I am using magento 2.3 version and i need to install SSL certificate to my domain. I installed lets encrypt certificate to my domain after that my admin is not logging in. It is showing login page with out error.

I verified following

1. BaseURL & secureURL is same
2. cookie_domain is NULL
3. I reinstalled the certificate
4. When i access https://domainname.com it is working but admin is not working. I changed baseurl and secureurl to https as well but admin is not logging in..
5. I cleared by browser cookies and tried to login . issue not resolved.
6. I tried to login with another browser , now the admin is logged in finely but when i access https://domainname.com then admin page is indirect loop.
7. Cleared magento cache and run deploy commands. But not worked.

Any solution?

Comment: I guess you might have an issue with secure flag in your PHP env. What is server are you use?

Comment: instead of leaving cookie domain null, try to set your real domain. If it's still not working, try to increase the max session size for admin using this command: ```bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000```

and if it still don't working, try to add this to your index.php

```if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution , Login to admin panel is working in another browser but when i access https all the css and js not rendering properly.